# Switching a conditional based on whether R session is interactive or not

Tags: r

Is there an environmental or global variable in R that I can use to switch between interactive and non-interactive versions of my code? This is important because there does not [appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980322/is-it-possible-to-specify-command-line-parameters-to-r-script-in-rstudio) that there is a way for an interactive session to accept command line arguments.  A related question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737046/switch-r-script-from-non-interactive-to-interactive)
 but it does not address my question.

An example of what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
if(ISINTERACTIVE){
    a <- 10
    b <- 6
}else{
    args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
    a <- args[1]
    b <- args[2]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This?

```
if(base::interactive()){
        a <- 10
        b <- 6
    }else{
        args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
        a <- args[1]
        b <- args[2]
    }
```