# about Error: protect(): protection stack overflow

Tags: r, macos

I am using Boruta package using Mac PC.

I got `"Error: protect(): protection stack overflow"` when I run Boruta.

The number of variable is 15000.

I used `options("expression" = 500000)`, but did not work.

Comment: Typo? `experssion` --> `expression`?

Comment: I edited. This is not a cause......

Comment: Okay, sorry. I am not familiar with that package, and without code or knowing something about the data, anything would be crude speculation. Good luck.

Comment: I am coding R --max-ppsize=500000 in command line. It is working, but how can we do this in Rstudio?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14980322/3358272. Perhaps your way forward is to do the hard work in a call to `Rscript` or using the `callr::` package.